# Oracle table with backup data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a package which I call like this:

```
BEGIN
    package.sp1();
    package.sp2();
END;
```

During this execution, a table is updated in procedures sp1 and sp2. However, I need to store a copy of that table as it was originally just in case something goes wrong and I need to restore the previous data. The data would only be copied on the first execution of each day. Then, the next day, the copied data would be used as a starting point to be updated in procedures sp1 and sp2.

How can I do that in another procedure?

This is what I want to do in pseudo-code:

```
BEGIN
    -- Fetch the data copied in yesterday's first execution
        package.sp1(); -- Updates the table
        package.sp2(); -- Also updates the table
    -- Store the updated data if this is the first execution of the day
END;
```

Comment: At what point, and how, do you determine that "something went wrong"?  What do you _expect_ to "go wrong"?  To do what you ask, you obviously need some method of determining if it is the first execution of the day.  But I suspect your entire concept of this 'backup table' and populating it only on the first execution of the day, is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Instead of saving the copy of the table, have you looked into `SAVE POINTS`?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm

Comment: @EdStevens I'm open to new ideas on how to achieve my requirements.

Comment: _" I'm open to new ideas on how to achieve my requirements"_   Well, first we'd need to know the actual requirements ... the _business_ requirements.  We'd need to know where the data is originating. We'd need to know _why_ you may run the procedure multiple times a day but only want to use the "start of the day" as your recovery point.  We'd need to know what it is you expect to go wrong.  Perhaps we should address the root problem there instead of this pre-conceived backup/recovery idea.

Comment: Business requirements: there's only production environment for a package. The first execution of the day is the one that stores the 'good data' in the table. After that, we manually save a copy of the 'good data' in another table and run tests/make changes. When we're done with these, we restore the copy having the 'good data' into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it turning back to the previous day's data to the Oracle's Flashback Query mechanism provided that the version your database is 10g+ along with some conditions satisfied such as

1. **undo_retention** parameter's *value* should be set at least to *86,400* which is in seconds, and equals to one day period.
2. undo tablespace should be with *autoextend* enabled or retention guarantee is enabled for fixed-size but having big volume undo tablespace.

Then use this query ;

```
DELETE tab;
INSERT INTO tab
SELECT *
  FROM tab
    AS OF TIMESTAMP TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
```

whenever something went wrong and needed to come back to the point in time for the data.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand though the 'DELETE tab' part. If I delete it, how would I insert the values?

Comment: you're welcome @banana_99 Oracle's undo segment holds your past data, past versions stay within the segment as long as the minimum requirements provided, and they will become extinct as the time passes depending on the undo_retention parameter's value and segment's extension style, and you already want to return back to the point in time, and need to delete all of the existing data in order to prevent duplicate insertion. You might [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-undo.html#GUID-F9B85E9D-D56A-43D2-AB52-918C0FE4D609).

Comment: [Using Oracle Flashback Query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-0BD1F4BD-894B-47BA-A44B-74BCA4CFD60E) might help too.

Comment: Thanks. Would Oracle Flashback Query work if the table is dropped and recreated?

Comment: you're welcome @banana_99 , no not possible, since those are DDL but not DML, we cannot go back to the point of time before issuing a DDL even it's of adding a new column to the existing table. You can look up **Flashback table** in order to recover an already dropped table, then. `FLASHBACK TABLE tab TO BEFORE DROP;` might be issued as a sample syntax.